Concurrent/parallel requests with vLL,
My question might be a bit basic, but I’m new to all of this and eager to learn.
I have build an app with FastAPI. Previously I used asyncio method to handle multiple request to llm, but with each new request it become slower in response. So I decide to use vLLM method, but I got a problem now how to provide parallel or concurrent requests to vLLM when I have dealing with dozen or more users. Is there a way to call run in parallel for several inputs and receive valid results for each input?
I have a basic setup where I initialize an LLM using vLLM with Langchain RAG and the Mixtral model (specifically, Mixtral8x7b). Here’s what I do:
I define a system prompt and an instruction f
I create an RAG system
I then run the RAG system  , which works for a single input and when I tested it with locust it works consistently.But I want it run parallel or concurrent.

How is your setup? Is everything in one container or do you have the LLM with vLLM running in its own container?

Now I'm just testing without docker container, so just running FastApi app, and with Locust trying to load and checking how many users concurrent requests it can handle at the same time.
